# About pointers ,array and malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

It is a real case from the puzzle.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define ROWS 10
    #define COLS 8

    void process_array(int array[ROWS][COLS]) {
            int i,j, count =0;
            for (i=0; i< ROWS ;i++)
                    for(j=0 ; j<COLS; j++)
                        array[i][j]= count++;



    }

    int main() {
    int **array = malloc( sizeof(int)*ROWS*COLS);
    process_array(array);

    /** int i,j;
        for (i=0; i< ROWS ;i++){
                    for(j=0 ; j<COLS; j++)
                        printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
                    printf("\n");
        }
    **/

        return 0;

    }
```

Questions.

(a) Bob wants to know if Alice’s code is correct. He uncomments the code from Line 21
to Line 26 to output the content of the array. What result will he get?

(b) Alice insists her code is absolutely correct (which is true). How can
he fix the problem if Bob does need to access the array in the main function via the
subscripting operators (i.e., `array[i][j]`)?

(c) Alice changes her function signature to

```
void process_array (int ** array ) ;
```

What is/are the corresponding modification(s) should Bob make to the main function?

(d) Another student Charlie advises Bob and Alice to use an one-dimensional array to
simulate a two-dimensional array. Bob then modifies Line 18 of the above code as
follows.

```
int * array=malloc ( sizeof ( int ) *ROWS *COLS ) ;
```

What are the further modifications should he make to the rest of the code? Let’s
assume that Alice wants to fall back to her original implementation.

Please give me a help.Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is my C teachers puzzle and want me to think deeper in pointer

Comment: That is why you should attempt the questions first, then ask for help. You won't learn much by asking for the answers!

Comment: okay I think it twice.Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typical case of type mismatch. `int ** array;` is not the same as `int array[5][6];`. The first gives you an `int*` on dereferencing, the second an array of 6 `int`s.

(a) Bob would get a `SIGSEGV` relatively quickly because he defined an `int **`, but Alice's function expects a `int (*)[COLS]` and that is what Bob actually allocated memory for.

(b) Bob would need to define `array` as

```
int (*array)[COLS] = malloc( sizeof(int)*ROWS*COLS);
```

or just allocate it on the stack

```
int array[ROWS][COLS];
```

(c) Allocate memory for each row.

```
int ** array = malloc( sizeof(int*) * ROWS);
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * COLS);
```

(d) Use the appropriate type, see above.

Comment: How to color the code???

Comment: @Clearner What do you mean? on stackoverflow it is coloured automatically.